# Bootstrap modal position on long list

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im currently working on a website where a table with a long list of data is being loaded. When scrolling down, each field has a button that can open up a Modal Window to view more information on that specific set of data. The Modal window however always opens up on the top of the page and is therefore not visible. I could handle this by scrolling up automatically but this is not a good solution. What could I do to make the Modal Window always open up in sight?

Code for Modal Window:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width:130%;" >
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">ID: {{trace.ID}}'s Details</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="overview">
              <p><span style="text-decoration:bold;color:#212529;">Login Name:</span> {{trace.WEBLGNNAME}}</p>      
              <p><span style="text-decoration:bold;color:#212529;">Datum:</span> {{trace.DATUM}}</p>
              <p><span style="text-decoration:bold;color:#212529;">Zeit:</span> {{trace.ZEIT}}</p>                
          </div>

        <!-- Stacktrace Field -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="comment"></label>
              <h5>Meldung</h5>
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" columns="10" style="font-size:12px;" readonly id="Meldung">{{trace.LOGTEXT}}</textarea>
              <div class="tooltip" title="In die Zwischenablage kopieren"><i ng-click="copyToClipboard('Meldung')" class="far fa-copy copy1"></br></i></div>
            </div>

          <!-- Stacktrace Field -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="comment"></label>
              <h5>Stacktrace</h5>
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" columns="10" style="font-size:12px;" readonly id="Stacktrace">{{stacktrace}}</textarea>
              <div class="tooltip1" title="In die Zwischenablage kopieren"><i ng-click="copyToClipboard('Stacktrace')" class="far fa-copy copy2"></br></i></div>
            </div>  

        <div class="logInfo">
          <div class="col1">
              <p><span style="text-decoration:bold;color:#212529;">Web Service:</span> {{trace.WEBLGNNAME}}</p>     
              <p><span style="text-decoration:bold;color:#212529;">Label:</span> {{trace.DATUM}}</p>
              <p><span style="text-decoration:bold;color:#212529;">Fehler Code:</span> {{trace.ZEIT}}</p>                 
          </div>

          <div class="col2">
              <p><span style="text-decoration:bold;color:#212529;">Programm:</span> {{trace.WEBLGNNAME}}</p>        
              <p><span style="text-decoration:bold;color:#212529;">SQL Code:</span> {{trace.DATUM}}</p>
              <p><span style="text-decoration:bold;color:#212529;">Fehler Typ:</span> {{trace.ZEIT}}</p>                  
         </div>

          <div class="col1">
              <p><span style="text-decoration:bold;color:#212529;">Prozedur:</span> {{trace.WEBLGNNAME}}</p>        
              <p><span style="text-decoration:bold;color:#212529;">SQL State:</span> {{trace.DATUM}}</p>
              <p><span style="text-decoration:bold;color:#212529;">Status BS:</span> {{trace.ZEIT}}</p>               
          </div>

          <div class="col2">
              <p><span style="text-decoration:bold;color:#212529;">Job User:</span> {{trace.WEBLGNNAME}}</p>        
              <p><span style="text-decoration:bold;color:#212529;">Job Name:</span> {{trace.DATUM}}</p>
              <p><span style="text-decoration:bold;color:#212529;">Job Nummer:</span> {{trace.ZEIT}}</p>                  
          </div>

          <div class="col1">
              <p><span style="text-decoration:bold;color:#212529;">Remote Addresse:</span> {{trace.WEBLGNNAME}}</p>       
          </div>
        </div>
```

Bootstrap v4.1.3, also using AngularJS Framework.

Comment: Where are you putting the modal div? I normally place all modals at the bottom of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Same place, with the only exception of ng-if="sessionCheck"

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with JQuery's Offset function. Code below.

Get Modal's current height

```
    var x = parseInt(document.querySelector('.modal-content').style.top);
```

Get windows height offset.

```
    var y =  parseInt($(window).scrollTop());
```

update modal's height offset. The reason I'm subracting the current modal's height from the windows height is because if you execute this function multiple times it always adds on top of what the current style is instead of replacing it.

```
    $('.modal-content').offset({ top: x ? y - x : $(window).scrollTop(), left: 0 });
```